# how to add css id for baselinkurl in jqgrid?

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

```
{
    name:'copyquiz',
    align:'center',
    index:'copyquiz',
    width:'100%',
    formatter:'showlink',
    formatoptions: {
        baseLinkUrl:'copy.php'
    }
}
```

in this column i want to add id(selector) for click event.

when i click link its open div with in the same page.

Comment: You're showing us something within squirlybrackets, mentioning a click and an ID, are we supposed to understand what it is your trying to do?

Comment: with in Squirlybrackets mention the column in jqgrid. when i click url its open content that is with in the div tag.